# 3D image rotation VTK using c#

Tags: c#, vtk

I'm trying to rotate a 3D image using VTK library and C# language.
The 3D image is a .STL image that I read using VTKRead then I define an actor like this `vtkActor actor_EtatObjet_Actuel = vtkActor.New();` 
as a global variable to rotate my image using a timer. For that I did

```
 private void timerRot_3D_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        actor_EtatObjet_Actuel.RotateX(30);

    }
```

My rotation doesn't work properly and it's waiting for me to click on the window's control. When I do it rotates. For example: my timer is defined on 1s so if i wait 3s and then click on the windows control my image will rotate 3*degrees?

I'd like to rotate it consequently each 1 second without clicking on the windows control.

how can I do that ?

Comment: How is your timer setup? Also, are you sure it's started correctly? If it doesn't rotate it doesn't sound like this piece of code is ever hit.

Comment: I don't know vtk but i know many engine. You might want to check if the viewer require a kind of update or refresh method being call so that it actually change what you see. By the look of it, since it wait for your interaction it means that is onpaint is still using old data (buffers) so there is very good chance your missing a Refresh/Update/Invalidate.

Comment: i'm working with the wpf . for the timer i'm sure it's start correctly, perhaps you're right, i didn't update my actor i'll tell tell you if it works

Comment: Hello Franck, my rotation finally worked it wasn't a problem of updating, now i have another problem is that it's rotate around the axe not  on the guide's Y axis,